# I don't know why these are not printing?... I am new to learning PHP... I am trying to input 2 numbers and return the larger of the two

Tags: php

This is my HTML file. I have two inputs where user will enter 2 numbers and submit for the "calculation".

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Larger of two numbers</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action = "largeroftwonum.php" method = "post">
      Enter your first number: <input type = "text" width = "5" maxlength="4" name = "first">
      <br>
      Enter your second number: <input type = "text" width = "4" maxlength="4" name = "second">
        <br>
        <input type = "submit" value = "Click to Submit">
        <input type = "reset" value = "Click to Reset">
    </form>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

And this is my PHP code. This is where it simply compares the two numbers and prints/returns the bigger number of the two.

```
        <html>
    <head>
        <title> Larger of two numbers PHP </title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
    $one = $_POST["$first"]; $two = $_POST["$second"];
    largerTwo($one, $two);
    function largerTwo ($one, $two) {
        if ($one > $two) {
            print "$one";
            return $one;
    } else {
            print "$two";
            return $two;
        }
    }
    ?>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Sorry in advance if it's such a simple task. I really need some guidance.

Answer (score 2):

The dollar sign in the double quote (`$_POST["$first"];`) means the value of `$first` that in your example is undefined.

Replace `$one = $_POST["$first"]; $two = $_POST["$second"];` by `$one = $_POST["first"]; $two = $_POST["second"];`

Answer (score 1):

Get the integer value of first and second.
Make an array with the two values: `[$first,$second]`
Return the `max()`value of the array.

```
$first = intval($_POST['first']);
$second= intval($_POST['second']);
$max= max([$first,$second]);
```

Best practice for PHP generated HTML there should be `<?php` only on line one and `?>` only on the last line.

```
<?php

$first = intval($_POST['first']);
$second= intval($_POST['second']);
$max= max([$first,$second]);

echo <<<EOT
<html><head><title> Larger of two numbers PHP </title></head><body>
Values = $first and $second<br>
The larger value is $max
</body></html>
EOT;
?>
```